# Do i have to state a "return nil" statement when my return value in a function is an optional?

Tags: swift, return, option-type, return-type

So for example i have the following code:

```
var meals: [String: Meal] = ["Breakfast": Meal(food: ["Bagel", "Orange Juice", "Egg Whites"], calories: 530)]

func logging (mealTime: String) -> Meal? {
 if let a = meals[mealTime] {
    return a
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```

Do i need to state a "return nil" if my return value is already an optional? Because the solution to this exercise was just this:

```
func logging(mealTime: String) -> Meal? {
    return meals[mealTime]
}
```

And if I do not have to add the return nil, why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify:

- **Parameter**:

  ```
  mealTime: String
  ```

This string could be a key in your dictionary.

- **Function** (how it works): this function wants to check if this key exists and if it is so, it returns the value (that is a Meal object).
- **What did you do?**

  ```
  if let a = meals[mealTime] {
    return a
  } else {
    return nil
  }
  ```

You are checking (if let) if there is a value with that string key and you are assigning that value to your constant (a). Eventually you return that value. If no value has that key in your array then you return nil.

- **What is the right answer about**?

Because this function returns an Optional Meal, you can skip checking if it exists, that's why the right answer is just:

```
    func logging(mealTime: String) -> Meal? {
        return meals[mealTime]
    }
```

This function returns **nil** if there is not value with that key and returns **the value** if it has that key.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, because the return type of the function is an optional i can also skip typing "return nil" because it automatically returns nil if the value does not exist for the given key in the dictionary?

Comment: Exactly! What you did works in case that function returns a Meal (not optional) but in your else statement you want to return a default Meal object (instead of nil)

Comment: @Dutchveteran's answer and the short answer return the same result in all cases.  A dictionary look up returns an optional that is the wrapped value if the key is valid or `nil` if the key is not present.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! @mrcfal